# Tkinter - key bindings not working correctly

Tags: tkinter, listbox, keyboard, bind, tkinter-entry

When I select something does not show up in Entry field, I have to press again Up/Down to work. The same for middle element - if is selected, I have to press again Up or Down to appear (but now, what is selected in the list it's different from entry field) . You have to press twice for a value to appear in entry field .

```
from tkinter import *

def selectItem(event): #puts the value in Entry field
    item = event.widget
    try:
        item != ()
        itemIndex = int(item.curselection()[0])
        valueItem = listbox1.get(itemIndex)
        lEntry.set(valueItem)
        print(event)
    except IndexError:
        return

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=1,fill=BOTH)

lEntry = StringVar()
listEntry = Entry(frame,textvariable = lEntry,width = 30)
listEntry.pack(side = TOP)

listbox1 = Listbox(frame,selectmode = EXTENDED)
listbox1.pack(side=BOTTOM)

listbox1.bind('<Up>',selectItem) 
listbox1.bind('<Down>',selectItem) 



for item in ["Youtube", "Linkedn", "Facebook"]:
    listbox1.insert(END, item)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback is currently bound only to key press events:

```
listbox1.bind('<Up>',selectItem) 
listbox1.bind('<Down>',selectItem)
```

You need to bind it to the listbox select event too:

```
listbox1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', selectItem)
```

Comment: Thank you. I  put <<>ListboxSelect>> and I can use mouse and arrow key now. :)